# Iterate folders in Datastore in Azure Machine Learning service

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

We have training pictures coming in to Azure blob storage. They are places in folders like
ProductA/yyyy-mm-dd, where the date is when the material was put in blob storage.

We have registered the blob container as a Datastore. When we run the training, we want to use the python sdk to create a Dataset, or a new version of the dataset, called ProductA and that should reference all date folders existing at that moment.

This is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-version-track-datasets#versioning-best-practice

In that example data is in folders called "Week xx". What is not described is how to know which all folders to reference when creating the dataset.

How can we access the blob storage to find the relevant folders to include? Can we use the Datastore to access files and folders directly?

Comment: One options is to create a dataset without registering it, get the files with to_path and iterating over them to find the folders from all the paths
dataset = Dataset.File.from_files((datastore, 'ProductA/**/*.jpg'))
dataset.to_path()

Comment: Usage of the wild card (as you mentioned) should be the easiest/best way. In case, exact dates needs to be mentioned in the path, it can be done in two steps: 1. construct the list containing exact paths (say: [(<datastore>, 'ProductA/2022-01-15/*.jpg'), (<datastore>, 'ProductA/2022-01-16/*.jpg')] using simple python code 2.  Using Azure storage API to verify if all those paths really exists 3. Pass the modified list to Dataset.File.from_files. This is exactly what I do.